# Deploying angular project to heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy angular project to heroku. I do all the steps and get the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) favicon.ico:1. Is the problem in the code or I did the setup wrong on heroku site.

```
{
  "name": "flashcards",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng start",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.17",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jwt-token-encrypt": "^1.0.4",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Flashcards": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Flashcards",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Flashcards:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Flashcards:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Flashcards:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Flashcards:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Flashcards:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "Flashcards"
}
```

I am trying to deploy angular project to heroku. I do all the steps and get the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) favicon.ico:1. Is the problem in the code or I did the setup wrong on heroku site.

Comment: You can sometimes diagnose problems by running `heroku logs -t` in a separate terminal window and then trying to launch the app again. From what I can tell this is a very generic error for an app failing to start in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku needs an express server to run our Angular application in production mode. Open a command window in the root folder of the Angular application. Execute the following command to install the express server.

```
npm install express --save
```

Create server.js file in your project folder:-

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const server = require('http').Server(app);


// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/your-application-name'));
 
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
 
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/your-application-name/index.html'));
});
 
// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port


server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("App running on port " + port);
})
```

Update the script in package.json file.

```
"start": "node server.js",
"postinstall": "ng build --output-path your-application-name --aot --prod",
```

Make sure dist file is not mention in .gitignore file.